# Create a reactive plot with plotly and shiny with specific gridlines ,marker color, background color and specific font

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

Hello I have a simple shiny app in which I create a scatterplot of variables found in the iris dataset. What I want is to be able to modify the plot in some ways. First of all I would like to be able to set the limits of the gridlines for each axis(by 1 for example), then set the background color to white and the marker color to blue and add trendline.

1. Preferred styles: Plot title - Calibri (or similar), 10 pt, bold,
   dark grey
2. Axis titles – Calibri light (or similar), 16 pt, bold, dark    grey
3. Axis number labels – Calibri, 11 pt
4. Data labels – Calibri, 9 pt, black
5. Data markers – dark 
               blue circles

I do not know if all of these or maybe some are available in ggplot2 in combination with plotly or I have to use only plotly  as Im new to it and would like some guidance.Thanks

## ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel(div("CROSS CORRELATION",style = "color:blue")),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(


    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",

                  tabPanel("Correlation Plot",
                           fluidRow(
                             column(3, uiOutput("lx1")),
                           column(3,uiOutput("lx2"))),
                           plotlyOutput("sc"))
      ))
  ))
```

## server.r

```
function(input, output) {




  output$lx1<-renderUI({
    selectInput("lx1", label = h4("Select 1st Expression Profile"), 
                choices = colnames(iris[,1:4]), 
                selected = "Lex1")
  })
  output$lx2<-renderUI({
    selectInput("lx2", label = h4("Select 2nd Expression Profile"), 
                choices = colnames(iris[,1:4]), 
                selected = "Lex2")
  })


  output$sc<-renderPlotly({

  p <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$lx1, y = input$lx2)) + 
    geom_point()
  ggplotly(p) %>% 
    layout(height = 400) 

  })

}
```

Comment: From a quick search, it looks like plotly will allow all basic theme options set in `ggplot` to show in the plotly output. All of the options you are considering would be done through `ggplot`'s `theme()` statement. See here for reference: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html .. Hope this helps!

Comment: It has some things but not what I need. I think that I should use only plotly and not ggplot2. Anyway thanks

Comment: Through `ggplot`'s theme? All of those options can be changed. `fontface` can be set to bold, `family` can be used to change the font, `color` can be used to change font color, data point shapes and color can be changed within the `geom_point()` option, etc... If you want, I can reproduce an unrelated plot that shows some of those options.

Comment: Would be helpful if you would! Can I change also the gridlines limits? For example not 0-2-4-6-8 but 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8.

Comment: So a reproducible with as many as possible of these options would be great

Comment: Hey @firmo, I posted an answer below that changes all the fonts to your desired options and shows how to change the tick label spacing. Let me know if there's any issues or more questions you might have. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, sorry for the delayed response, but here's a working example that changes all the features you requested. It was a bit more involved than I lead on... Calibri isn't a font that is built into R, so it needs to be loaded in using [`font extra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/extrafont.pdf) package. Then, most of the options you wanted to change were simple to do within [`theme()`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) arguments, but the hover text needed to be changed within the [`plotly`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/) call options. Hope this example helps with your code!

```
## Note: extrafont is a bit finnicky on Windows, 
## so be sure to execute the code in the order 
## provided, or else ggplot won't find the font

# Use this to acquire additional fonts not found in R
install.packages("extrafont");library(extrafont)
# Warning: if not specified in font_import, it will 
# take a bit of time to get all fonts
font_import(pattern = "calibri")
loadfonts(device = "win")

# Load the packages
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# Just use cars data frame
p <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
  # Change the point options in geom_point
  geom_point(color = "darkblue") +
  # Change the title of the plot (can change axis titles
  # in this option as well and add subtitle)
  labs(title = "Distance vs Speed") +
  # Change where the tick marks are
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30, 2.5)) +
  # Change how the text looks for each element
  theme(title = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                             size = 10, 
                             face = "bold"), 
        axis.title = element_text(family = "Calibri Light", 
                                  size = 16, 
                                  face = "bold", 
                                  color = "darkgrey"), 
        axis.text = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                 size = 11))
ggplotly(p) %>%
  layout(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white", 
                           font = list(family = "Calibri", 
                                       size = 9, 
                                       color = "black")))
```

Comment: great and complete answer I will aceept it! One question..it is a small detail but how can I change the default grey background of the plot from grey to white and the gridlines from white to grey?